# How to adjust height for the input tag?

Tags: html, css

I have a list of radio-buttons with a label assigned to them:

```
<input id="iphone" type="radio" name="mobilephone" value="iPhone4">
<label for="iphone">iPhone 4</label>
```

But I removed the standard radio-buttons and replaced it with my own .png:

```
input[type="radio"]{
    display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]+label{
    background: url('../img/empty.png') left center no-repeat;
    padding-left: 45px;


}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label{
    background-image: url('../img/filledout.png');
}
```

**But the image is too big, so the border gets cut out.** It only changes if the text-size is greater, so the picture has more space to show up.

**How can i set the height of the input?**

No matter how big the text gets, the minimum-size of the input should be as high as the image!

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Give `height` and `width` for `label` and use `background-size` for the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the CSS for the `input` tag, you have to explicitly specify the `height` and `width` attributes of the radio button, using `px` or `em` units. You should set it to the maximum size you need for the image. A good demo you can use:

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Answer (score 0):

You can change the size of the background by typing:

```
background-size:10% (for example 10%)
```

or:

```
background-size:10px 10px;
```